# Java: Multiple Loop Function Not returning

Tags: java, string, parsing, for-loop, stringbuilder

Given a polynomial, for example, `5x^4 - 1x^2 +2x^2 -3 +5x` I create the following three arrays whose indexes match up with the variable,degree, and coefficient that each "item" in the polynomial has.

```
variableArray = [x,  , x, x, x]
degreeArray   = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4]  //sorted on
coefficentArray=[5, -3, 2, -1, 5]
```

I am attempting to write code that adds up all of the "items" with the same degrees and same variable, and returns a String of the new polynomial, so for instance what I'm looking for here would be `5x^4 + 1x^2 + 5x -3`. Here is my function so far...

```
    public static String putItTogether(int[] array,int[] array1, String[] array2, int count)
{
    int j = count; //count is number of items in arrays
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=count; i<=0 ; i--) {
         int answer = 0;
         while (array[j] == array[j-1]) {                         //array = degrees //array1 = coefficients // array2 = variable
              if (array2[j] == array2[j-1]) { //variable
                    answer = array1[j] + array1[j-1];//coeff
              }
         j--;
         }
      String coefficientString = Integer.toString(answer);
      String degreeString = Integer.toString(count);
      builder.append(coefficientString);
      if (array2[i].equals("x")) {
          builder.append("x");
      }
      if (array[j] != 1) {
         builder.append("^");
         builder.append(degreeString);
      }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The call...

```
String daAnswer = putItTogether(degreeArray, coefficientArray, variableArray, degreeCount);
    System.out.println(daAnswer);
```

For whatever reason, it's not printing out anything. If you could look over my code, and see where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it. Also, any questions about what I'm asking please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Never compare strings with ==. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Fixed that issue, but still can't figure out why nothing is printing out?

Comment: Issue is : for (int i=count; i <= 0 ; i--)  please use this one  for (int i=count; i >= 0 ; i--)

Comment: Got it to run, but for the polynomial `5x^2+5+6x+6x^2+6x^3` it returned `0^50x^50x^50x^50x^50^5`

Comment: Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: you are using <= where i= 5 that time 5<=0 is failed so it not going inside of loop. so you need to use condition >=

Comment: Pankaj, I already changed that. It made my function return something, but what it returned was wrong. See above what I put in and what it returned